# Adding pdf pages Dynamically using PDFBox

Tags: java, spring-boot, pdfbox

I am trying to add pdf page dynamically when content exceeds the limit of page. It gives this error.Please review the below code and help me with a solution.

{
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error: You must call beginText() before calling endText.
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream.endText(PDPageContentStream.java:385)
at PDFUtility.content(PDFUtility.java:123)
at StudyConfigImpl.getStudyConfigPDF(StudyConfigImpl.java:39)
at Main.main(Main.java:6)
}

```
 private float addParagraph(PDPageContentStream contentStream, float width, float sx,
                                 float sy, String text, boolean justify,float initY,float pageHeight,PDDocument document) throws IOException {
    PDFont FONT = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;
    float FONT_SIZE = 7;
    float LEADING = -1.5f * FONT_SIZE;
    java.util.List<String> lines = parseLines(text, width);
    contentStream.setFont(FONT, FONT_SIZE);
    contentStream.newLineAtOffset(sx, sy);
    float totalHeight = initY;
    for (String line: lines) {
        float charSpacing = 0;
        if (justify){
            if (line.length() > 1) {
                float size = FONT_SIZE * FONT.getStringWidth(line) / 1000;
                float free = width - size;
                if (free > 0 && !lines.get(lines.size() - 1).equals(line)) {
                    charSpacing = free / (line.length() - 1);
                }
            }
        }
        contentStream.setCharacterSpacing(charSpacing);
        float fontHeight = FONT.getFontDescriptor().getFontBoundingBox().getHeight() / 1000*FONT_SIZE;
        totalHeight -=fontHeight;
        System.out.println(totalHeight);
        if(totalHeight - StudyConfigImpl.PAGE_MARGIN <= 0){
            PDPage nextPage = new PDPage();
            nextPage.setMediaBox(PDRectangle.A4);
            document.addPage(nextPage);
            totalHeight = pageHeight - StudyConfigImpl.PAGE_MARGIN;
            contentStream.endText();
            contentStream.close();
            contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document,nextPage);
            contentStream.beginText();
            contentStream.setFont(FONT,FONT_SIZE);
            contentStream.newLineAtOffset(StudyConfigImpl.INIT_POSITION_X,StudyConfigImpl.INIT_POSITION_Y);
        }
        contentStream.showText(line);
        contentStream.newLineAtOffset(0, LEADING);
    }
    return (lines.size()*(7+3));
}




 public float content(
        PDPageContentStream contentStream,
        float initX,
        float initY,
        float pageHeight,
        float width,
        float height,
        Map<Object, Object> studyData,
        PDDocument document
        ) throws IOException {
    int counter = 0;
    for(Map.Entry<Object, Object> entry : studyData.entrySet()){
        if(entry.getKey().equals("Additional Notes") || entry.getKey().equals("Study Desc.")){
            initY-=25;
            contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD,7);
            contentStream.beginText();
            initX = 20;
            contentStream.newLineAtOffset(initX,initY);
            contentStream.showText(entry.getKey().toString());
            float sy = addParagraph(contentStream,555,0,-10,entry.getValue().toString(),true,initY,pageHeight,document);
            contentStream.endText();
            initY -=sy;

        }else{
            contentStream.addRect(initX, pageHeight - initY, width, height);
            contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD, 7);
            contentStream.beginText();
            contentStream.newLineAtOffset(initX, initY);
            contentStream.showText(entry.getKey().toString());
            contentStream.newLine();
            contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA, 7);
            contentStream.showText(entry.getValue().toString());
            contentStream.endText();
            initX += width;
            counter++;
            if (counter == 5) {
                initX = 20;
                initY = initY - 20;
                counter = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return  initY;
}
```

Comment: In `addParagraph()` you assign a new `PDPageContentStream` to `contentStream` but this new value is not returned to `content()`. Thus, `content()` continues working with the old content stream and calls `endText` for it again. This triggers the exception.

Comment: So what do i do? Can you provide any solution for this.@mkl

Comment: *"So what do i do? Can you provide any solution for this."* - See the section "A work-around" of my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The cause

In `addParagraph()` you conditionally assign a new `PDPageContentStream` to `contentStream` but this new value is not returned to the caller `content()`:

```java
private float addParagraph(PDPageContentStream contentStream, float width, float sx, float sy, String text, boolean justify, float initY, float pageHeight, PDDocument document) throws IOException {
    ...
            contentStream.endText();
            contentStream.close();
            contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document,nextPage);
            contentStream.beginText();
    ...
    return (lines.size()*(7+3));
}
```

Before re-assigning `contentStream` you in particular call `endText()` for the old stream.

Thus, content() continues working with the old content stream and calls `endText()` for it again:

```java
public float content(PDPageContentStream contentStream, float initX, float initY, float pageHeight, float width, float height, Map<Object, Object> studyData, PDDocument document) throws IOException {
    ...
            float sy = addParagraph(contentStream,555,0,-10,entry.getValue().toString(),true,initY,pageHeight,document);
            contentStream.endText();
    ...
    return  initY;
}
```

Calling `endText` for a content stream that has no open text object triggers the exception you observed.

#### A work-around

Both `addParagraph` and `content` appear to be methods of the same class (or at least in two classes one of which is derived from the other). Thus, you can make `contentStream` a member variable of that class instead of forwarding it as parameter:

```java
public class PDFUtility {
    public PDPageContentStream contentStream = null;

    private float addParagraph(float width, float sx, float sy, String text, boolean justify, float initY, float pageHeight, PDDocument document) throws IOException {
        ...
    }

    public float content(float initX, float initY, float pageHeight, float width, float height, Map<Object, Object> studyData, PDDocument document) throws IOException {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

and in `StudyConfigImpl.getStudyConfigPDF` instead of

```java
float y = pdfUtility.content(contentStream, initX, ...);
```

you do

```java
pdfUtility.contentStream = contentStream;
float y = pdfUtility.content(initX, ...);
contentStream = pdfUtility.contentStream;
```

This work-around obviously requires that the same instance of your class is not used concurrently from different threads.